# why the nvidia drivers are never up to date?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, repository

Just out of curiosity. Maybe there are some technical reasons why the drivers are not up to date.

14.04 64b In additional drivers I have 331, but at the nvidia website they have 340. I'm coming back now to ubuntu, but before, lets say 6 months or 1 year ago was the same. The repositories were always behind.

Comment: Give more details, OS version, ...

Comment: 14.04 64b In additional drivers I have 331, but at the nvidia website they have 340.

Comment: The question is just that. I don't know, I feel it weird. why so long to up date? Maybe the changes in the drivers are not big enough to test it or nvidia drivers just suck. I wanted to know what is ubuntu thinking.

Answer (score 1):

The drivers available  via additional drivers are focused on stability and have been tested to assure it. You can still download and install the the latest drivers from nvidia's site and install them yourself.